# Unfortunately SQlLiteApp Has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am using a CRUD Operation using sqllite. but when I am going to run the program is shows the following error. Here I have given below my databasehelper.java file & mainactivity.java file code.

Here is my DatabaseHelper.java file code.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student_Table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "SUBJECT";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, SURNAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, SUBJECT VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name,String surname,String subject){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,subject);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return  true;
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editName,editSurname,editSubject;
    Button btnAddData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
        editSurname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_SurName);
        editSubject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Subject);
        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        AddData();
    }

    public void AddData(){
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),editSurname.getText().toString(),editSubject.getText().toString());
                        if (isInserted == true)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

When I'm going to save the data it shows the following message

> "Unfortunately SQlLiteApp has stopped.."

Comment: Show us the logcat

Comment: where is your log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forget to add space after `CREATE TABLE` and  `EXISTS` therefore change

```
"CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID
```

to

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID
```

and

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME
```

to

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME
```

Note: please uninstall app before retry.

Comment: Thanks a lot..its Working

Comment: @kishor Happy to help,enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

From your logs:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEStudent_Table": syntax error (code 1)
Use the following: In short add space after table and after Exists

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, SURNAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, SUBJECT VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL);");
```

On Upgrade:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +";");
```